# why I'm getting error when I want rewrite String[ ] with duplicate to String[ ] without duplicate

Tags: android

Hi I have String[] array with repeating data.
I want to rewrite this array to new String[] array2, without duplicate.

```
Cursor c;
    c= myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM BusPlan", null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    int columnCnt = c.getCount();           
    String[] stringArray = new String[columnCnt]; //deklaracja tablicy stringArray
    String[] stringArray2 = new String[columnCnt];

    for(int i = 0; i < columnCnt ; i++){         
        String variable= new String();
        variable=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Bushaltestelle"));
        stringArray2[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Bushaltestelle")); 
        c.moveToNext();                             
        for (int j=0;j< columnCnt;j++){
            if(!variable.equals(stringArray2[j].toString())){
                stringArray[j]= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Bushaltestelle"));
            }
        }

    }
```

what I'm doing wrong?
How to make it working?

I solved problem using Hashset, but I'm not happy from that.

```
Spinner spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    Cursor c;
    c= myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM BusPlan", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int columnCnt = c.getCount();
    String[] stringArray = new String[columnCnt]; //deklaracja tablicy stringArray
    String[] stringArray2 = new String[columnCnt];
    for(int i = 0; i < columnCnt ; i++){
        stringArray[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Bushaltestelle"));
        c.moveToNext();}
    stringArray2 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArray)).toArray(new String[0]);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Bodo.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,stringArray2); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText(stringArray[16]);
```

If someone know how to make it working using arrays I'll be glad for info

Comment: Use Set which doesn't allow duplicate value. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html

Answer (score 0):

In your for (int j loop your overwriting all data thats not equal to the new data. Try this:

```
Cursor c;
c= myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM BusPlan", null);

c.moveToFirst();
int columnCnt = c.getCount();           
String[] stringArray = new String[columnCnt]; //deklaracja tablicy stringArray
String[] stringArray2 = new String[columnCnt];

for(int i = 0; i < columnCnt ; i++){         
    String variable = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Bushaltestelle"));
    stringArray[i] = variable; 
    c.moveToNext();
    if (variable == null)
        continue;
    for (int j=0;j< columnCnt;j++){
        if (stringArray2[j] != null && variable.equals(stringArray2[j].toString())) {
            break; // duplicate so ignore
        }
        if (stringArray2[j] == null) {
            stringArray2[j]= variable; // new empty slot, all already added data has already been passed by the loop
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: at line: 'if (variable.equals(stringArray2[j]).toString)' LogCat give me : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @TomaszOkraszewski sorry forgot that stringArray2[j] would be null sometimes, edited the answer to be correct

Comment: Then your table must contain null in Column "Bushaltestelle" for some entries. I changed the code so they will be ignored

Comment: Yes, you are right. Last row is null. I'll try it tomorrow. Thx.

Comment: I'm sorry. It does't work : FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Still the same line, or a other one?

Comment: if (stringArray2[j] == null)

Comment: I really don't see how that can be because if `stringArray2[j]` is null it wouldn't throw an exception, but simply return true. So `stringArray2` must be null, but that can't be since we're setting it to `String[] stringArray2 = new String[columnCnt];` and afterwards not changing it anymore.

Comment: The only way I could imagine to create a `NullPointerException` in that line would be by using `stringArray2[j].equals(null)` instead